# ReactJs / window.open / onload дочернего окна

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open

По кнопке происходит запрос, который возвращает данные в открытую, по window.open, страницу. Забираю данные следующей конструкцией:

```
  const newWindowFunc = () => {
      const newWindow =  window.open(url);

          newWindow.onload = function() {
              //здесь забираю данные
          };
      };
  };
```

Но это не работает, если на дочерней странице сначала происходят какие-то действия, уже после которых редиректит на урл с нужными данными. Т.е. в новом окне сначала кидает на гугл авторизацию и потом редиректит на урл моего домена.
Как в reactjs можно слушать изменения на этой странице, чтобы дождаться последнего события onload и получить доступ к странице в рамках одного домена?

Comment: useEffect.....?

Comment: Да, на ум тоже сразу пришел useEffect. Но реализация подкачала. Если можно, то конкретный пример обновления плз :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Опять же буду очень благодарен конкретному примеру. Я пробовал postmessage, но в моем случае при нажатии на кнопку происходят следующие действия: запрашивается авторизация на гугл и после согласия редиректит на урл, который возвращает нужные данные. Т.е. сама страница пустая, там только данные которые вернулись, а событие onload не ловит момент когда уже произошел редирект именно на страницу домена, поэтому добавить функцию для работы postmessage не выходит.

Comment: И если бы я понимал момент когда моя страница прогрузилась, то это бы и не потребовалось. В рамках одного домена данные и так были бы доступны